# Integrating Datadog RUM data into Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, datadog

My team is trying to integrate datadog's RUM data into Snowflake for our data scientists to consume. Is this possible? If so how?

So far I have found documentation on how to integrate data from snowflake into the datadog dashboard, but not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of options:

- Use an ETL tool that can connect to both Snowflake and Datadog
- Bulk load: export the data to an S3 (or similar) file and use the Snowflake COPY INTO command
- Streaming: stream the data out of Datadog and then into Snowflake using Snowpipe

Answer (score 0):

Poll the RUM events API with an application you develop yourself.

https://docs.datadoghq.com/api/latest/rum/

Write microbatches to your target tables using one of the language connectors, or the Spark connector.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/spark-connector-use.html